# why is remove() not working

Tags: firebase, web

I have search solutions but still I cant delete the data in my database.
This is my code.

```
  if (e.target.classList.contains('delete')) {
  idd.value =  feedbackNode.querySelector('.feedback_id').innerText;
   var vfeedbacksref = db.ref('feedback');
  vfeedbacksref.orderByKey().once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
     snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
      childSnapshot.forEach(function(data) {  

        if(idd.value == data.key){
          console.log(data.key);
          vfeedbacksref.child(data.key).remove();

       }
  }
```

My database looks like this.

```
feedback{

 "1" : {
   "-Kuwhb8N9YmqQulgHSLe" : {
   "date_created" : "26/09/2017",
   "feedback" : "cool spot",
  "feedback_id" : "-Kuwhb8N9YmqQulgHSLe",
  "rate" : "2.0",
  "to_user_id" : "1",
  "user_id" : "TTV9rnGW1wPm0sNFgbkn1qX01Ci2"
   }
 "2" : {
   }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Is an error message generated, is the remove update not performed, or something else? A description of what you observed and what you want to happen would be helpful.

Comment: It has no error but it is still not able to delete the data.

Comment: try `childSnapshot.child(data.key).remove();`

Comment: it says   childSnapshot.child(...).remove is not a function

Comment: how you defined `vfeedbacksref`

Comment: var vfeedbacksref = db.ref('feedback');                                                        
  its the reference to my database.Sorry, I forgot to include it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to delete `feedback/1/-Kuwhb8N9YmqQulgHSLe`.

When you try this `vfeedbacksref.child(data.key).remove();` it is pointing to `feedback/-Kuwhb8N9YmqQulgHSLe` which give error because no such node present in the `feedback`

try this `vfeedbacksref.child(childSnapshot.key).child(data.key).remove();`

Comment: The childSnapshot is the first child(1). What I want to delete is the data inside the second child(-Kuwhb8N9YmqQulgHSLe).

Comment: then try `data.remove();`

Comment: But I tried your suggestion and it says childSnapshot.remove is not a function

Comment: It gives an error "TypeError: data.remove is not a function.."

Comment: Ok somewhere i seen like this `childSnapshot.ref().remove` try that too.I have no idea how it work but give it a try

Comment: It still says that  childSnapshot.ref is not a function. Is ref() a function?

Comment: Thank you Hareesh! I've successfully deleted my data. Thanks for the time. :D You're awesome.